# Why am I getting 404 when I hit my domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I deployed my web app in AWS Amplify and after successful completion of deployment when I try to access the link provided in domain I am getting 404 error and the message is:
This dev.mylink.amplifyapp.com page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://dev.mylink.amplifyapp.com/ HTTP ERROR 404
Can anyone help to resolve this issue

Tried troubleshooting for this and some of them are:
checked whether routing is correct
cleared cache and refresh
checked for proper build steps
but not found any issue in any of the above